# ChicagoBoss failed to run on version OTP18.1

Tags: chicagoboss

I am currently using newest erlang version otp/18.1 to run ChicagoBoss, but I see this error

```
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/datumwiine/ChicagoBoss-0.8.15/deps/riak_pb: rebar_abort
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing in the command line the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss.git
cd ChicagoBoss/
make
```

Comment: and try a "make clean"